# Find the limit $\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{1}{\arcsin x}-\frac{1}{\sin x}\right)$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

> Find the limit $$\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{1}{\arcsin x}-\frac{1}{\sin
>  x}\right)$$

\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{\arcsin x}-\frac{1}{\sin x}\right)&=\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\sin x-\arcsin x}{\sin x\times \arcsin x}\right)\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{\arcsin x}
\cdot\frac{x}{\sin x}\cdot \frac{\sin x-\arcsin x}{x^2}
\end{align}

Here's where I'm stuck. I know from L'Hopital's Rule that $\frac{x}{\sin x}\to 1$, but what about $\frac{x}{\arcsin x}$? Or is there any other way than using L'Hopital to solve this question?

Comment: yes use lhopitals

Comment: Even without L'Hopital $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is a known limit. $\frac{x}{\arcsin x}$ is the same limit, just substitute $x = \sin\theta$

Comment: @NinadMunshi what do you mean by $x=sin\theta$?

Comment: Plug it in and see what happens.

Comment: but then it will be $\lim_{sin\theta\to0}\frac{sin\theta}{\theta}$

Comment: Oh, by $sin\theta\to0$ it implies that $\theta\to0$, correct?

Comment: It's an odd function: if it has a limit, the limit must be zero.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$\dfrac{\sin x-\arcsin x}{\sin x\cdot\arcsin x}=x\cdot\dfrac{\dfrac{\sin x-x}{x^3}-\dfrac{\arcsin x-x}{x^3}}{\dfrac{\sin x}x\cdot\dfrac{\arcsin x}x}$$

Now use [Are all limits solvable without L'Hôpital Rule or Series Expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387333/are-all-limits-solvable-without-lh%c3%b4pital-rule-or-series-expansion)

Comment: Actually, you have to write $x^2$ instead of $x^3$.

Comment: @Angelo no: in the numerator there is a sum, in the denominator a product

Comment: You are right, I am sorry.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{1}{\arcsin{x}}-\frac{1}{\sin{x}}=\frac{1}{x+\frac{x^3}{6}+...}-\frac{1}{x-\frac{x^3}{6}+...}\rightarrow0.$$

Your way  also helps because $$\frac{\sin{x}-\arcsin{x}}{x^2}\rightarrow\frac{\cos{x}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}}{2x}\rightarrow\frac{-\sin{x}-\frac{x}{\sqrt{(1-x^2)^3}}}{2}\rightarrow0.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$L=\lim_{x\to 0} \left( \frac{1}{\sin^{-1} x}-\frac{1}{\sin x}\right)$$
Note that if $|x|$ is very small then $\sin^{-1} x=x+x^3/6+..., \sin x=x-x^3/6+... (1+x)^{k}=1+kx+...$
Then $$L=\lim_{x \to 0} \left( \frac{1}{x+x^3/6}-\frac{1}{x-x^3/6} \right)$$
$$\implies L=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1}{x}[(1+x^2/6)^{-1}-(1-x^2/6)^{-1}]=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1}{x}[(1-x^2/6)-(1+x^2/6)]=0$$